# Sum of geometric series from discrete maths

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics

My discrete maths book Gives proof for The sum of geometric series as:

$$\ S = \sum_{j=0}^n ar^j = \frac{(ar^{n+1}-a)}{r-1}$$

When r != 1,

And the next line reads:

Clearly, when r = 1, then, the sum is:

```
                       (n+1)a
```

I don't understand the clearly part, What I could clearly see was only then when r = 1, the expression took an indeterminate form.

How was the (n+1)a expression obtained?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $r = 1$, we have $r^j = 1$, and thus we just add $a$ $(n+1)$ times (from $j=0$ to $j=n$).

Answer (score 0):

When $r=1$ you have $$S = \sum_{j=0}^n a\times 1^j = \sum_{j=0}^n a = a+a+\cdots +a = (n+1)a$$